# Flat module, dependence linear

Tags: modules, flatness

Anyone help me this question

Show that a R-module $M$ is a module flat if only if, such if exist R - dependence linear $\displaystyle \sum a_i m_i =0$ of elements of $M$ , will be exists  $a_ij \in R$  and $m_{j}^{'} \in M$, such $\displaystyle \sum a_{ij}a_i = 0 \ \forall j$ and $m_i = \displaystyle \sum _{j} a_ij m_{j}^{'}$.

Thanks in advance

Comment: For the implication $M$ flat $\Rightarrow \cdots$, see Lang's Algebra, lemma 3.10 - the statement of the lemma asks for $M$ to be flat and finite, but I don't see that the finiteness matters.

Comment: Oops - I forgot to say Chapter XVI ( lemma 3.10 ).